# php facebook event rsvp

Tags: php, facebook, events

I have an event on facebook I would like to rsvp attending to.  I would like to rsvp with a link, all the examples I have found for rsvping were done with forms.  I have the rsvp_event permission and an active access_token.  The actual problem I am facing is redirecting after a successful http post.

```
<?php
     $redirect_uri = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
     $access_token = "ACCESS_TOKEN";
     $eid = "EVENT_ID";

     $rsvp_to_event = "https://graph.facebook.com/$eid/attending?method=post&access_token=$access_token&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri";
?>

<a href="<?php echo $rsvp_to_event; ?>">Join</a>
```

Clicking the 'Join' link will rsvp to the event, but leaves me on a page displaying true.  Any ideas to get the page to redirect after a successful rsvp?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to query that URL using cURL or `file_get_contents()`, here's an example from my [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-check-status-and-rsvp-to-facebook-events-using-graph-api-fql/61/):

```
<?php
$app_id = "APP_ID";
$app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
$my_url = "REDIRECT_URI";
$event_id = "EVENT_ID";
$rsvp_status = "";

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
    $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&scope=rsvp_event";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
}

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
. "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
. "&code=" . $code;
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

if( isset($_POST['rsvp']) ) {
    // Form submitted, call the Graph API to RSVP to the event
    $event_rsvp = "https://graph.facebook.com/$event_id/{$_POST['rsvp']}?method=post&" . $access_token;
    $rsvped = json_decode(file_get_contents($event_rsvp));
    if($rsvped) {
        $msg = "Your RSVP status is now <strong>{$_POST['rsvp']}</strong>";
        $rsvp_status = $_POST['rsvp'];
    }
}
if( !$rsvp_status ) {
    $query = "SELECT rsvp_status FROM event_member WHERE eid=$event_id AND uid=me()";
    $fql_url = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?"
        . "query=" . urlencode($query)
        . "&format=json"
        . "&" . $access_token;
    $fql_resp = json_decode(file_get_contents($fql_url));
    $rsvp_status = $fql_resp[0]->rsvp_status;
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create An Event</title>
<style>
label {float: left; width: 100px;}
input[type=text],textarea {width: 210px;}
#msg {border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px; color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php if( isset($msg) ) { ?>
<p id="msg"><?php echo $msg; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="privacy_type">RSVP:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rsvp" value="attending" <?php if($rsvp_status==="attending") echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>Attending&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="rsvp" value="maybe" <?php if($rsvp_status==="maybe" || $rsvp_status==="unsure") echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>Maybe&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="rsvp" value="declined" <?php if($rsvp_status==="declined") echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>Not Attending&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="RSVP to this event" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You should be looking at:

```
if( isset($_POST['rsvp']) ) {
    // Form submitted, call the Graph API to RSVP to the event
    $event_rsvp = "https://graph.facebook.com/$event_id/{$_POST['rsvp']}?method=post&" . $access_token;
    $rsvped = json_decode(file_get_contents($event_rsvp));
    if($rsvped) {
        $msg = "Your RSVP status is now <strong>{$_POST['rsvp']}</strong>";
        $rsvp_status = $_POST['rsvp'];
    }
}
```

The above tutorial consist of HTML form where the user can choose his status.

Comment: I actually found your tutorial from google searches before i posted this question.  Originally I wanted to create a html link to rsvp attending.  I tried adapting your tutorial from a form to a link.  Didn't work out too well, so I followed your tutorial and made a rsvp form like yours.  Works great, hanks for the guidance.

Comment: Oh glad to hear that! :D    I guess I should get back to tutorial writing again then!

Answer (score 0):

Most graph api endpoints are not designed to be called directly with your user's browser but to call them from your backend code (authentication related ones could be exception).

Try using the [offical php sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) for sending those requests from your php page, or just use the [curl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or `file_get_contents` on these endpoints from your php script and redirect the user yourself.